# join tables using array saved in database to be used to match tables

Tags: mysql

I need to join three tables where I got this data from database 1-1|2-0|3-2|4-0. When you break this down it will be come 1-1, 2-0, 3-2, 4-0, where the first number is "addon_id" and second number is "option_id" respectively separated by dash. This is the data I was told to work on to.

```
1-1, 2-0, 3-2, 4-0

paired
addon_id - option_id
  1      -     1
so on...

addon_id = (1,2,3,4)
option_id = (1,0,2,0)

table photo_addons
addon_id  addon_name   addon_price
1         test1        123.00
2         test2        456.00
3         test3        125.00
4         test4        112.00

table photo_options
option_id  option_name  option_price
1          opt1         50.00
2          opt2         40.00
3          opt3         35.00


In this next table it is where you will find what options are in each addons:

table option_items
id  addon_id  option_id
1   1         1
2   1         2
3   2         1
4   3         1
5   3         2
6   3         3
```

Result should be like this:

```
addon_name   addon_price   option_name   option_price
test1        123.00        opt1          50.00
test2        456.00                      0.00
test3        125.00        opt2          40.00
test4        112.00                      0.00
```

Here what I tried so far

```
SELECT pa.addon_name, pa.addon_price, po.option_name, po.option_price
FROM photo_addons as pa 
LEFT OUTER JOIN option_items as oi
ON (oi.addon_id = pa.addon_id AND oi.option_id IN (1,0,2,0))
LEFT JOIN photo_options as po
ON po.option_id = oi.option_id
WHERE pa.addon_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

but with this, it is displaying the option_id that shouldnt be displayed

Comment: here

SELECT pa.addon_name, pa.addon_price, po.option_name, po.option_price
FROM photo_addons as pa 
LEFT OUTER JOIN option_items as oi
ON (oi.addon_id = pa.addon_id AND oi.option_id IN (1,0,2,0))
LEFT JOIN photo_options as po
ON po.option_id = oi.option_id
WHERE pa.addon_id IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: but with this, it is displaying the option_id that shouldnt be displayed